# iText: how to detect if a pdf page is LETTER or LEGAL size

Tags: java, itext

I have a pdf documents that contains mixture of LETTER and LEGAL size, and I need to detect pages with LEGAL size and reduce to LETTER size. Can I do this with iText? sample code would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use

- http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html#getPageSize(int)
- http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html#getPageSizeWithRotation(int)

Compare the width and height of the Rectangle you get out of this and you know what paper size you're using.

Comment: for some reason, when I try direct compare, like this `if(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(i).equals(PageSize.LETTER))`, it does not work. But if I compare with and height, then it works. Must be that `Rectagle` class does not have `equals and hashcode` implemented.

Comment: http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/index.html?com/itextpdf/text/Rectangle.html Not from the looks of this API.